# How to fetch Azure Security Insights Object ID from terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform

I need to add Azure Sentinel Automation Contributor role on Azure Security Insights App. To do it, how can I get the objectId of Azure Security Insights App which is present in Enterprise Applications in Azure Active directory via terraform?

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "sentinel_contributor" {
  scope              = "/subscriptions/<subId>/resourceGroups/<rg>"
 // role_definition_id = azurerm_role_definition.sentinelcontributor.id
  role_definition_name = "Azure Sentinel Contributor"
  principal_id       =  "3367a746-xxx18686"#objectid of azure security insights app 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `objectId` of **Azure Security Insights** App which is present in Enterprise Applications of Azure Active directory via terraform, you can make use of below code:

```
data "azuread_service_principal" "security_insights_app" {
  display_name = "Azure Security Insights"
}

output "security_insights_app_object_id" {
  value = data.azuread_service_principal.security_insights_app.object_id
}
```

I have **Azure Security Insights** app in Enterprise Applications of my tenant like below:

[image]

When I ran below terraform code, I got `ObjectID` of **Azure Security Insights** app in response successfully like below:

```
data "azuread_service_principal" "security_insights_app" {
  display_name = "Azure Security Insights"
}

output "security_insights_app_object_id" {
  value = data.azuread_service_principal.security_insights_app.object_id
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: Tried the same approach .. but facing the below error  ServicePrincipalsClient.BaseClient.Get(): unexpected status 403 with OData
error: Authorization_RequestDenied: Insufficient privileges to complete the
operation. How to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Make sure to assign `Application.Read.All` API permission or `Application Administrator` role to your terraform service principal.

Comment: ok.. let me try it out

Comment: Thanks a lot .. It worked for me after applying Application.Read.All API permissions